# How do you localize static UIApplicationShortcutItems?

Tags: ios, localization, 3dtouch

I have an application and I want to add a mix of static and dynamic app shortcut items.  Localizing for dynamic items is pretty straightforward, using `NSLocalizedString`, but not so much with the items in your info.plist.  I already have an InfoPlist.strings file for localizing the name of my application, but I am less sure about how static `UIApplicationShortcutItems` would work since these items do not have a unique key.

**How do you localize static UIApplicationShortcutItems?**

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Turns out that the app will search the InfoPlist.strings file for a corresponding key matching the value in the Info.plist.  That might sound a little confusing, so here's an example:

For the `UIApplicationShortcutItemTitle` key in the info.plist, add a value of, say, `ADD_ITEM_SHORTCUT_TITLE`:

```
<key>UIApplicationShortcutItemTitle</key>
<string>ADD_ITEM_SHORTCUT_TITLE</string>
```

This value will then need a corresponding entry in your InfoPlist.strings file:

```
ADD_ITEM_SHORTCUT_TITLE = "Add Item";
```

Comment: This no longer works on Xcode 8 beta 6 ... Any one else figured out what the alternative is?

Comment: @shrutim I am unable to reproduce your issue on Xcode 8 beta 6.  Are you sure that you have everything setup correctly?  You might consider asking a new question.

Comment: Yes .. it was my bad. Our team did localization and split the files but didnt copy this over. It does work on Xcode 8 beta 6

Comment: Create a new infoPlist.strings file is necessary. I added the localization string another string file :(

Comment: Yoiu don't need to write ADD_ITEM_SHORTCUT_TITLE as this also seems to work: "Add Item" = "Add Item";

Answer (score 21):

Add one new string file and save it with name "InfoPlist.strings"
[image]

Enable Localization for this file, and add string with title like below explanation.

[image]

Now Open your info.plist file and add title like below.

[image]