# How to localise array of string inside the iOS info.plist file

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, localization, plist

I have already achieved localisation for simple string based on following link  **https://stackoverflow.com/a/25736915/529294**

now i want localise for array of string on plist, please check the attached file, i have annotate the needed values on image[image: info.plist]

i need to localise the **URL type->URL Schemes**

Comment: i need localise the following values facebookappid, displayname and url types.   how localise "url types" value to "InfoPlist.strings" file ?

Comment: Add this to your question, not as an comment. You can edit your own question.

Comment: i also edited the question

Comment: Not a duplicate, but with the same solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32773149/how-do-you-localize-static-uiapplicationshortcutitems

Answer (score -3):

Click on infoPlist. And check in the file inspector. There is an option called localize. Click that and select the languages you to localize this file.[image]

Comment: This won't work, we cant localize the info.plist directly,
 we need localize the "InfoPlist.strings" and also i have achieved simple key,string values, i need to string of array.